# sending data from controller to a typeclass in symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony-3.2

i'm trying to get data from the database and pas it to the form's drop down list

this is the Entity from where i'm looking to get the data from, specifically the type column

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\TypesRepository")
* @ORM\Table(name="types")
*/
class Types
{

 /**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Column(name="idtype",type="integer")
 */
 private $idtype;
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
 private $type;
```

and this is the type class that holds the form,as you can see i created a construct based on some internet cherche that i have done, the constructer adds the passed value to the variable, then it's called in the EntityType

```
class sell_form extends AbstractType
{

protected $cat;

public function __construct (Types $cat)
{
$this->cat = $cat;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{


$builder


->add('categorie',EntityType::class,array(
                       "required"=>false,
                        'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Types',
                        'choices' => $cat
                        ))

                        ;
                ;
 }
 }
```

and finaly this is the controller where i inisialize the $cat variable from the database using a repository function

```
/**
  * @Route("/Old/buy", name="old_buy")
*/
public function Old_buyAction()
{

return $this->render('/user_module/Old Views/Old_buy.html.twig');
        }
/**
   * @Route("/Old/sell", name="old_sell")
   *@Method({"GET","POST"})
*/
public function Old_sellAction()
{
$cat = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Types')-
>tn();



 /*line 122 */



$form = $this->createForm(new sell_form($cat));
 //$form = $this->createForm(sell_form::class,$cat);
 return $this->render("user_module/Old Views/old_sell.html.twig",array(
                                          "myForm"=>  $form->createView(),


                                    ));
```

## this is the error that it's shown

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to 
AppBundle\Forms\sell_form::__construct() must be an instance of 
AppBundle\Entity\Types, array given, called in 
C...\OldController.php 
on line 122 and defined`
```

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code expects to pass `AppBundle\Entity\Types` instance, but you pass an array of them. Change typehint in `sell_form` constructor.

Comment: **Thank you very much @MateuszSip for your help** Bot can you please clarify more?

Answer (score 0):

`$cat` is an array of `AppBundle\Entity\Types` instances. You pass them into form constructor:

```
public function __construct (Types $cat)
{
    $this->cat = $cat;
}
```

At this moment your code expects that `$cat` is a single `Types` instance, so it crashes:

> AppBundle\Forms\sell_form::__construct() must be an instance of 
>   AppBundle\Entity\Types, array given

You need to expect an array:

```
public function __construct (array $cat)
{
    $this->cat = $cat;
}
```